# Open a specific Evernote note with hotkey

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, evernote

On my Mac, I'm currently using [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) to open up a text file in TextMate when I press a hotkey. I use this file as a sort of scrap pad. I paste junk in there for later.

But I'd like to start using Evernote for this. Do you know of a way to open up a specific Evernote note with a hotkey? Or, does Evernote store notes as files so I can use the same kind of procedure I was using before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to right-click on the note in the menu of Evernote and choose "Copy Note Link" item. Paste the link into your hotkey definition, and the note should open by the hotkey. This works on Windows, don't have Mac to check right now, but should work there as well.

Comment: That was easy! Exactly what I was after.